# How do I use a HTML filter in macro arguments in Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

I have something like this: `[% query | html %]`

Now I would like to use it as

```
[% MACRO l(text, args) BLOCK; c.localize(text, args); END; %] 
[% l('text:<b>[_1]</b> no:[_2]', [query | html,2]) %]
```

If you try that example it will not work because `|` cannot be used there. That is not accepted by Template Toolkit. I want to HTML-escape `query`. How can I do that?

To move `<b>` out of the quotes is not a solution because the translation may not have the same order as above.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Can you post a complete (but short) example that we can run through tpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `[% USE HTML %]` and [escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Plugin/HTML.pm#escape%28text%29) a specific parameter, for example:

```
[% USE HTML %]
[%# your code above %]
[% l('text:<b>[_1]</b> no:[_2]',  HTML.escape(query), 2) %]
```

Comment: not possible because the reality is more complicated than that. I am going to update the example because the order of arguments may not stay the same.

Comment: Updated now that you changed your question